# How to access advanced custom field values within a gutenberg block?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have a custom post type with a few advanced custom fields. I'm trying to access these custom field values from within a Gutenberg block.

I've added the following to my `register_post_type` function

```php
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields' ),
```

I can successfully retrieve the custom posts from within my Gutenberg block using:

`select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'customType')`

but I'm not seeing the custom fields or their values.

Here's my block's JavaScript:

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { withSelect } = wp.data;

registerBlockType('cgb/block-press-block', {
  title: __('Press Block'),
  icon: 'awards',
  category: 'common',
  keywords: [
    __('press-block'),
  ],
  edit: withSelect((select) => {
    return {
      posts: select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'press')
    };
  })(({posts}) => {
    return <p>Content</p>;
  }),
});
```

Is there a way to access the custom post's advanced field values on the editor side or a way to pass that data to the block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using Advanced Custom Fields already, are you able to rather than registering your own block independently, use `acf_register_block` instead? That way you can access fields from ACF in PHP based templates.

Here are some useful links about this:

- [ACF 5.8 – Introducing ACF Blocks for Gutenberg](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/blog/acf-5-8-introducing-acf-blocks-for-gutenberg/)
- [acf_register_block()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_register_block/)

This code is taken from the ACF blog post above and posted here for completeness in case the above link changes.

Register the ACF block:

```
add_action('acf/init', 'my_acf_init');
function my_acf_init() {

    // check function exists
    if( function_exists('acf_register_block') ) {

        // register a testimonial block
        acf_register_block(array(
            'name'              => 'testimonial',
            'title'             => __('Testimonial'),
            'description'       => __('A custom testimonial block.'),
            'render_callback'   => 'my_acf_block_render_callback',
            'category'          => 'formatting',
            'icon'              => 'admin-comments',
            'keywords'          => array( 'testimonial', 'quote' ),
        ));
    }
}
```

A callback function to include your block template:

```
function my_acf_block_render_callback( $block ) {

    // convert name ("acf/testimonial") into path friendly slug ("testimonial")
    $slug = str_replace('acf/', '', $block['name']);

    // include a template part from within the "template-parts/block" folder
    if( file_exists( get_theme_file_path("/template-parts/block/content-{$slug}.php") ) ) {
        include( get_theme_file_path("/template-parts/block/content-{$slug}.php") );
    }
}
```

The HTML of your block:

```
<?php
/**
 * Block Name: Testimonial
 *
 * This is the template that displays the testimonial block.
 */

// get image field (array)
$avatar = get_field('avatar');

// create id attribute for specific styling
$id = 'testimonial-' . $block['id'];

// create align class ("alignwide") from block setting ("wide")
$align_class = $block['align'] ? 'align' . $block['align'] : '';

?>
<blockquote id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="testimonial <?php echo $align_class; ?>">
    <p><?php the_field('testimonial'); ?></p>
    <cite>
        <img src="<?php echo $avatar['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $avatar['alt']; ?>" />
        <span><?php the_field('author'); ?></span>
    </cite>
</blockquote>
<style type="text/css">
    #<?php echo $id; ?> {
        background: <?php the_field('background_color'); ?>;
        color: <?php the_field('text_color'); ?>;
    }
</style>
```

This creates a basic *testimonials* block as a simple starting point. ACF handles the JavaScript handling within Gutenberg so all you have to do is worry about the PHP side of things.

That means you get to use [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) and [`the_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) function like we're (*ACF fans*) are used to. Mixing ACF and Gutenberg without using this native way may cause headaches and possibly require a plugin to access fields via the WordPress REST API.

**Note: ACF support for Gutenberg blocks requires ACF version 5.8 or higher.**

Comment: So I'm using [create-guten-block](https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block) which allows me to create multiple blocks within one plugin. I was hoping to avoid having to create a separate plugin. Is there a way I can just add this functionality to my current plugin?

Comment: Yeah you can use the ACF block functionality in your own plugin if you want to.

Comment: I didn't realize ACF 5.8 is still in beta. I'll see if I can upgrade and use `acf_register_block` in my current config. If not, I might have forgo using Gutenberg blocks and just render the custom post content in a template.

Comment: I ended up using this functionality and was able to easily retrieve all the custom post type data I needed. Thanks!